# ASP.net (MVC 3) - How to get content by url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, variables

How can I get a different content, by the URL's variable (I think it's called Query Strings)?
Examples to what I wish to achieve:

```
Content(string page)
```

http://mysite.com/Content?**page=about**
<-- will show the about page.

http://mysite.com/Content?**page=store**
<-- will show the store page.

Thanks.

*P.S. I realize I can just make a page for the about and make a page for the store (in this example), but I want it like I asked.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth adding a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ContentRoute",
    "Content/{page}",
    new { controller = "Content" action = "Content", page = (string)null });
```

The model binder should pick up the query argument and pass it into the call to the controller action.

Comment: can you give me a reference that explains these stuff? I'm new and I don't understand.

Comment: You can start here... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: Ok, I read it, but where will the Content page get the content that matches the query string?

Comment: Well, that's entirely up to you. I'm assuming you need to read it from a databasse, and return it as `return Content(...)`. Oh, the other thing, your method `public ActionResult Content(string page)` will likely conflict with the base `Content` method which is used to return a `ContentResult`.